# HTML input date. Как сделать ввод даты, чтобы год был двухзначным?

Tags: javascript, html, дата, input

Как кастомизировать поле input с типом Date, чтобы в вводе год заполнялся только 2 цифрами?

Например, 18.01.22.

У меня сейчас 18.01.2022

Подойдет любое решение, даже поле с типом TEXT, но маской ввода, как у дате. Не могу найти такую маску.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключите на проект jQuery и плагин jQueryMask Plugin
2. Добавьте ваш код в теги скрипт

```js
$(function() {
    //2. Получить элемент, к которому необходимо добавить маску
    $('#closedDate').mask('AA.SS.YY', {
        'translation': {
            A: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
            S: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
            Y: { pattern: /[0-9]/ }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Поправьте ваш код пожалуйста, сейчас при запуске у вас ошибки

Comment: да по-моему уж лучше воспользоваться сразу Datepicker от jquery, там и настроек всяких больше